# Relations between Bessel functions

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, bessel-functions

Consider the following two couples of functions:

- [Bessel function of the first kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BesselFunctionoftheFirstKind.html) $J_{\nu}$ and [Bessel function of the second kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModifiedBesselFunctionoftheSecondKind.html) $N_{\nu}$, also known as $Y_{\nu}$;
- [modified Bessel function of the first kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModifiedBesselFunctionoftheFirstKind.html) $I_{\nu}$ and [modified Bessel function of the second kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModifiedBesselFunctionoftheSecondKind.html) $K_{\nu}$.

The second couple is used for the general solution of the [modified Bessel (homogenous) differential equation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModifiedBesselDifferentialEquation.html):

$$f(x) = A I_{\nu}(x) + B K_{\nu} (x) \label{a} \tag{1}$$

But the same general solution can still be written in terms of the first couple as

$$g(x) = C J_{\nu}(ix) + D N_{\nu} (ix) \label{b} \tag{2}$$

where $i$ is the imaginary unit, according to the definition itself of the modified Bessel differential equation.

Which coefficients $C, D$ must be given to the functions in $\ref{b}$ in order to obtain the solution $\ref{a}$?

$C = i^{-\nu}$ immediately leads to $I_{\nu}(x)$, but I can not figure out how to proceed about the remaining part, not knowing a direct relationship between $K_{\nu}$ and $N_{\nu}$.

---

From an alternative perspective:

The linearly independent functions $I_{\nu}(x)$ and $K_{\nu}(x)$ generate the space of solutions of a modified Bessel differential equation. But also the linearly independent functions $J_{\nu}(ix)$ and $N_{\nu}(ix)$ generate the **same** space of solutions.

Can, then, the couple of functions $I_{\nu}(x)$, $K_{\nu}(x)$  be expressed in terms of $J_{\nu}(ix)$, $N_{\nu}(ix)$? If not, why?

If this were linear algebra, the answer would be yes. What instead about functional analysis?

Comment: You might check this Wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts Thank you, I didn't notice it at a first glance. If you want to make an answer, I will choose it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might check this Wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function